# Loading Google Map Markers via PHP file in XML format

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot addresses from my db via xml format. I have got a PHP file that plot these addresses in xml format, and I would like to display them into google map as markers.

generatexml.php working fine, it display all addresses as xml format but I can't figure out how to plot these addresses into map as marker.

Result of generatexml.php

```
<markers>
<marker address="Lichfield Road, Burton on Trent, United Kingdom"/>
<marker address="Anchor BuildingsWestgate, Morecambe, United Kingdom"/>
</markers>
```

Here's my php file that generate xml file.

```
 // file name  generatexml.php
    require ('connection.php');


    // Start XML file, create parent node
     $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
     $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
     $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
     // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());}
    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection ,$database );
   if (!$db_selected) {
     die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
     }
  // Select all the rows in the markers table

   $query = "SELECT * FROM mapping WHERE 1";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
   header('Content-type: text/xml');
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
     $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);

       }

       echo $dom->saveXML();

       ?>
  <script>
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=mykey&sensor=false">
  </script>

 function initialise() {
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.559323,-3.321304);
mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),         
  mapOptions);

xmlUrl = "inc/generatexml.php";

loadMarkers();

     }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

Any idea or examples ?

Comment: How many total addresses do you need to display?  You can't plot addresses per se.  You need to geocode them to get the coordinates.  More than about 10 addresses will run into the geocoder's quota/rate limit.

Comment: What does your `loadMarkers` function look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: For reference, here are the usage limits for the Geocoding API: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits). It's at 5 requests per second for the free API.

Comment: You are missing a `?` in your maps API call. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...`